# After changing parentNode.innerHTML, can't access parentNode

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have the following DOM structure and scripts

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.parentNode.innerHTML += 'hello';
console.log(test.parentNode); // null
console.log(document.getElementById('test').parentNode); // normal result
```

```html
<div>
<div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

As above script says, the first outputs `null` while the second outputs the actual node, does anyone know why the first output `null` rather than the normal node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After resetting `innerHTML` property, browser parses the set contents and creates *new* elements. The `test` variable doesn't refer to the new element which also has `test` id. The original `test` element is detached from the DOM and has no parent element. `test` and `document.getElementById('test')` refer to different DOM Element objects.

Use the `createTextNode` and `appendChild` methods instead and see the difference:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.parentNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode('hello'));
console.log(test.parentNode);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, silly me, obviously a easy-understood question.

Answer (score 3):

val += b is actually the same as val = val + b. When written this way, it should be more obvious that you are recreating all elements inside parent.

If you want to append without destroying existing elements, use appendChild and not innerhtml.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, silly me, obviously a easy-understood question.

Answer (score 2):

Your code in English would say:

- Get me a reference to the DOM node with ID 'test'
- Now take that DOM node out of the DOM tree and replace it with a new node with the text `<div id="test"></div>Hello` (not a typo, it will put exactly that string in).
- Now show me the parent node of the DOM node you took out of the tree (aha! but it's no longer in the DOM!)
- Now get a reference to a DOM node with the ID "test" (it finds the thing that you inserted in step two.
- Show me the parent of that node (no problem)

The original DOM node 'test' is still in memory, but no longer in the document. You can see this by looking at `test.innerHTML`, you will see it still has just the original text, because you're looking at the DOM node in memory.

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.parentNode.innerHTML += 'additional text';
console.log(test.parentNode); // null
console.log(test.innerHTML);
console.log(document.getElementById('test').parentNode); // normal result
```

```html
<div>
<div id="test">Original text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, silly me, obviously a easy-understood question.

Comment: with `but no longer in the DOM` you mean `document`

Comment: Not at all silly HaibaraAi, you actually had me stumped until I went and fiddled in the fiddle :). @alexander farkas, thanks, will edit.

Answer (score 1):

The following line:

```
test.parentNode.innerHTML += 'hello';
```

is a shortcut for:

```
test.parentNode.innerHTML = test.parentNode.innerHTML + 'hello';
```

This means that test is removed and replaced by the same markup + the string `"hello"`. But your test reference is not in the document anymore.

You can try

```
test.parentNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode('hello'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, silly me, obviously a easy-understood question.

Answer (score 0):

While appending html using `test.parentNode.innerHTML += 'hello';`(which is equal to `test.parentNode.innerHTML = test.parentNode.innerHTML + 'hello';`), it's actually recreating the element so, `test`(which is reference to the element) is no longer available in dom.

Instead  create textNode using **[`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode)** method and append using **[`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)** method which keep the other elements.

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.parentNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode('hello'));
console.log(test.parentNode);
console.log(document.getElementById('test').parentNode);
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, silly me, obviously a easy-understood question.